# How should I write this answer where $zw$ is purely imaginary?

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $z=2-i$ and $w=a+bi$, where a and b are real numbers. For which values $a$ and $b$ is $zw$ purely imaginary?

My approach:

$zw=(2-i)(a+bi)=2a-ai+2bi+b=2a+b+i(2b-a)=i$

$\left\{\begin{matrix}
2a+b=0 \\
 (2b-a)i=i 
\end{matrix}\right.$

$0=2(2b-1)+b=4b-2+b=5b-2$, $b=\frac{2}{5}$

Then I stopped and looked at the solutions manual and found that $a=-b/2$. $2a+b=0$ gives this, but I would rather have answered with $b=\frac{2}{5}$ and the real value of $a$. Is this a matter of taste, or about how you are supposed to write "it" mathematically correct, or what?

> How should I write the answer where $zw$ is purely imaginary?

Comment: It is not the matter of taste. "$zw$ is purely imaginary" is not the same condition as "$zw=i$", and you swapped one for the other. No wonder you got a different (smaller) set of solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just asked to find out the values that $a$ and $b$ take if $zw$ is imaginary.

However, they haven’t specified **what value** it should take. So, the condition that $$zw = i$$ is wrong. Why can’t it be $-3i$ or $\pi i$ for that matter?

Just the first condition is enough: the real part of $zw$ $=0$.